# How to make Windows 7 aware about iPhone photo orientation

Tags: iphone, photos, picasa, orientation

When transferring photos from the iPhone to the PC, the photos are not showed by Windows Explorer in the correct orientation, but I know there is some EXIF info in the photo with the orientation information, because Picasa shows them in the correct way.

[image: demo]

I have to save them with Picasa, so Windows can show them ok.

**Is there some patch or program to correct this behavior?**

Comment: No idea about how to solve this (if this is even possible) but you're not the only one complaining about this: http://www.windows7taskforce.com/view/1600 .

Comment: And http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/windows-photo-viewer-or-live-photo-gallery-does/a161c8da-c1ce-4347-a92e-724f9e535c15?auth=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just realized that using the "Import pictures and videos" wizard rotate the photos for you.

Comment: You haven't answered your own question. You've answered another question, i.e. 'how to rotate iPhone photos on Windows7'. The underlying issue is that support for the Exif orientation is incredibly inconsistent among browsers, operating systems, and other photo tools. See [EXIF orientation handling is a ghetto](http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/) for details.

Answer (score 5):

I just found this software: [**JPEG-EXIF autorotate**](http://www.pilpi.net/software/JPEG-EXIF_autorotate.php).
I've not tried it and can't tell if it works fine or not, but they say it works with Windows 7.

Apparently it adds an entry in the context menu to rotate automatically the image according to the EXIF orientation data. So if you select a bunch of images, their orientation will be corrected and so will it be for the thumbnails. Not entirely what you're looking for but I don't have better for the moment.

Comment: Tested it, it works, but is kind of clunky.

Answer (score 5):

Windows Photo Viewer ignores the EXIF rotation information when displaying the photo, Picassa does not. Personally I think both behaviors are correct; you do want some tools to show you what the JPEG's native orientation is, though it would be nice if the viewer had the option to enable "view rotation according to EXIF data".  The solution you found, of importing the pictures, will actually change the file to rotate the JPEG data according to the EXIF and then update the EXIF to not rotate the image. That's okay, but not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried Picasa but it does NOT keep the correct orientation of my iPhone 3G photos. Neither does Windows Live Photo Gallery. Interestingly *SOME* photos are rotated correctly, but most are not. The rotation seems to happen quite randomly.

The orientation is correct when importing with iPhoto on the Mac though, unsurprisingly.

But as I'm switching from Mac to PC this has become a rather annoying bug.